# Motherboard won't reboot unless left unpowered for a couple of hours after shutdown

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, reboot

I have a machine with an ASUS X99 Deluxe II Motherboard. Everything works fine but I notice that if I power it down, it won't reboot (e.g., via the power button on the motherboard itself) unless I pull the power cord out of the power outlet and leave it unpowered for a couple of hours. Anyone seen something like this before - what could be the explanation?

Comment: Have you replaced the PSU?

Comment: That means something goes wrong in the shutdown process and the BIOS gets into an illegal state. Have you tried to press the rest button before switching it on? Make sure you have the latest BIOS installed and I would enable ErP mode which disables most of the systems that can stay online after power down (saves also power).

Comment: Are you certain the power button powers it down? Maybe it just puts the machine in stand-by mode or hibernation mode and the problem is that the OS is not able to get out of that mode? Did you try pushing the power button for 5-10 seconds? (generally, this forces immediate power down and it is not desirable in every day use, but in your situation it may help determinate what is going wrong)